# Swift Generic function not accepting input

Tags: swift, generics, pattern-matching

So I am learning Swift with a focus on pattern matching and generics. I am running into an issue with the code below:

```
indirect enum MyList<A> {
  case Cons(A, MyList<A>)
  case Nil
}
func length<A>(_ list: MyList<A>) -> Int {
switch list {
    case .Nil:
        return 0
    case .Cons(_, let b):
        return 1 + length( b)
}
}
print(length( MyList.Cons(1, MyList.Cons(2, MyList.Nil))))
print(length(MyList.Nil))
```

When I try and run the code on an online swift playground I get the error

```
 error: generic parameter 'A' could not be inferred
      print(length(MyList.Nil))
```

Now what I am having trouble understanding is why this is an issue, I understand how if I were to use extensions this would work but I don't see why the code wouldn't work as it is now. For instance when I comment out the `print(length(MyList.Nil))` code the code will compile and behave as expected. I can only edit the length function, any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In your above code, you are trying to call a **generic function**, which requires a type.

So, you need to specify the **type** like:

```swift
print(length(MyList<Any>.Nil))
```